# Camel routes take a long time to shut down gracefully

Tags: java, activemq-classic, apache-camel

I'm deploying 30-some Apache Camel v. 2.10.3 routes directly into ActiveMQ. ActiveMQ starts up in a few seconds and Camel replies that it started all routes in about 2 seconds.

There are no external systems connecting to ActiveMQ, nor any messages flying through Camel. I then wait a few seconds and press "Ctrl-C" (on windows) to terminate ActiveMQ. Camel then starts its gracefully shutdown procedure...

My problem is that ActiveMQ is not able to shutdown all the routes within the 300 seconds. No matter what I do, it continues to report that it takes 375 seconds to shutdown Camel.

I've tried setting the start-up order on the routes, but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

I've had the same routes deployed on ServiceMix without problems before.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.

I had renamed my broker to something over than "localhost" but had asked Camel to connect to vm://localhost. This resulted in the following: http://fusesource.com/kbs/show/?id=193592-warn-brokerregistry-broker-localhost-not-started-so-using-other_broker_name-instead.

When I asked Camel to connect to vm://mybroker, then it worked as expected.

Comment: Yes, but only after a few days. Godt arbejde Claus!